# Listing RDS reserved instances using Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm looking through [Boto's online docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html#module-boto.rds) for RDS and I'm not seeing anything that lets me list/purchase Reserved Instances.  Am I overlooking something?  I know Boto has RI support for EC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  Looks like they have not been implemented yet.  If you want to create an issue on github, we can try to get them in there.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I'll take a look and possibly add it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I'd like to document that newer versions of Boto3 already implemented a method for getting reserved RDS instances:

```
client.describe_reserved_db_instances()
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_reserved_db_instances

Maybe it helps someone in the future :)